# Spring data jpa - Aggregate list of values in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I have the following (simplified) entities:

```
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users;

    ...
}

@Table(name = "users")
public class StoredUser extends StoredBase {

    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Group> groups;

    ...
}
```

So I wanted to get something like list of username group by groupId:

```
group_id   group_name   username
---        ---          ----
1          gr1          1, 2, 3
2          gr2          4, 5
3          gr3          1, 4
```

At first I was just using `groupRepository.findAll()` and convert the response based on that. But the amount of unrelated data coming with Group and User is big and is slowing down the response. So I want to fetch just the related values only.

So I wonder what is the best way to achieve this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

group_concat and a 'group by' should get you there.

Something like (untested, but someone will be along to tell me if I'm being fick):

```
select g.group_id, g.group_name, group_concat(u.username) as all_users
from groups as g join users as u on g.users = u.id
group by u.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah it might not be exactly it but it give me some idea how to solve it.
JPA doesn't accept group_concat as it is but I can try native query at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use projections from Spring Data JPA. In your case, create interface:

```java
interface GroupAndUsers{
    String getId();
    String getName();
    Set<Integer> getUsersId();
}
```

and add following method to your repository:

```java
List<GroupAndUsers> findAllGroupAndUsers();
```

Comment: I doubt it could be as simple as that, what I want is username, and I don't think JPA would be able to detect that from such method.

Comment: I know, but recently I used specification API so JPA is powerful but configuration will be tedious. Using native query is better choice.